# To edit data retrieved from database in django

Tags: python, django

I have retrieved data from the database and displayed it in a table.
Now Onclick of EDIT button I want to edit the table. Below is my code. But nothing is happening. I am not able to edit the content. Not getting any error.
I am a newbie. Plzz help..

My views.py file

```
def editquestiondata(request, id):
    info = Trans.objects.get(pk = id)
    info.transtype_id = request.POST.get('editexplain')
    info.save()
    return HttpResponse('updated')
```

My urls.py file

```
url(r'^editquestiondata/$', 'booki.account.views.editquestiondata', name='editquestiondata'),
```

HTML Template

```
<table border="1" style="width:800px">
<button type="button" value="Edit explain" name="editexplain">Edit</button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Changes Saved!')">Save</button>
<tr>
  {% for s in questdata %} 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>   {{ s.script }} </td>
<td>   {{ s.id }} </td>
</tr>    

  {% endfor %} 

</table>
```

Comment: Where is the template with the edit form?

Comment: First things first, Your URL pattern does not match your view's signature

Comment: And how are you expecting that Edit button to work? You don't seem to have any code for displaying fields that the user can edit in.

Comment: The data is displayed..

<th><p><a href="/accounts/question" target="iframe_c">FocusingInformation</a></p> </th>

On click of the link.. The data is displayed in the iframe. 

<iframe name="iframe_c" width="80%" height="800px" align="right"></iframe> 

<button type="button" value="Edit explain" name="editexplain">Edit</button>

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer...

My HTML template

```
enter code here

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" style="width:900px">

<tr>
   {% for s in details %} 
</tr>
<form action=" " method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value={{ s.id }} name="sid" />
<tr>
<td>   
       {{ s.script }}
  {% if s.id == sid %}
        <input type="text" name="script" value="{{ s.script }}" />

  {% endif %}
</td>

<td> <a href="/accounts/newexplain/?sid={{ s.id }}">Edit</a> </td>

</form>
</tr>    

  {% endfor %} 

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Views.py file

```
enter code here

def editexplain(request):
    info = Trans.objects.all()
    if request.POST:
      sid = request.POST.get('sid')
      edit = info.get(sid=s.id)
      edit = request.POST.get('script')
      edit.save()
      return render(request, 'newexplain.html', {'info':info, 'sid':sid})
```